# Does each instance of SQL Server on a cluster require its own LUN?

Tags: sql-server, cluster-computing, failovercluster, san

I'm setting up a Misc SQL Cluster (Windows 2008/SQL 2005 & 2008) that will be active/active and have about a dozen SQL instances on it. From the documentation I've read, I can't tell if each SQL instance will need its own LUN, or if I can have a single, really big LUN created, and then create a dozen different partitions on that LUN (one for each SQL instance).

In either case, the physical disk layout on the SAN won't change, so it really doesn't matter from a performance standpoint which one I choose (assuming I can choose either). I just want to know if the partition method works, or if each instance needs to own its own LUN to handle the failover properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance will need separate disks/LUNs.
They will be "owned" by the active node and are a dependent resource.

If you think about it, how can 2 SQL Server instances share a drive? It's a conflict.

Since Windows 2003 you can use NTFS mount points, that is mount a LUN in an empoty folder in a drive. I've not tried it myself though.

Edit: some nice pictures here "[How do Cluster Shared Volumes work](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/100867/q-how-do-cluster-shared-volumes-work-in-windows-server-2008-r2.html)"

Comment: It turns out that, while SQL Server supports "map points" in a cluster, you can't get around the drive letter limit using them. The base of your map point has to also be on a clustered drive, and that drive has to belong to same group as your SQL process. As such, it needs to fail over with your SQL process, so you can't have all the LUNs mapped to a single location. Oh well -  I suppose I'm limited to 24 instances anyway just based on the fact that it's a ton of instances to manage...

Answer (score 1):

You will need separate disks for each instance.  In Server 2008 you will add the shared storage for each instance in the Failover Manager.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if there is a way to use CSV (Clustered Shared Volumes) to get around this. In Windows 2008 R2 you can set it up so that you can have more than one node in a cluster access the same LUN - no longer do you have to assign a LUN to one node only!!